# Prevent iFrame from loading twice with jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, iframe

Is it at all possible to prevent an iFrame within a jQuery Mobile site from being called a second time when JQM auto-initializes and enhances the DOM? We're running into an issue where the page is redirected incorrectly because on arrival at the page, a cookie is destroyed and so when the DOM is loaded again the iFrame is called a second time, but without the cookie it breaks and redirects.

To reiterate, I want the same iFrame to persist during jQuery Mobile initialization.

Comment: @Reigel Use your imagination. But no need, I just realized that I could insert the HTML on pageinit. $(document).on('pageinit',function() { $('#iframe').html(//string with iframe tag) });

Comment: am I obligated to use my imagination? :D